# Android java weird behaviour with recyclerview

Tags: android, rest, android-recyclerview, realm

ive a metod which check that internet connection work or no.
Also ive two metods - if internet works get data from api and load in recyclerview and it's work correctly, but when im copy the same metod to the "offline mode" and change, that the data will load from Realm Database im getting error like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

At the point i dont know why im getting it, below some code which generate my problem:

```
else if(isOnline() == false){
        try {
            RealmResults<ResultModel> obj = realm.where(ResultModel.class).findAll();
            for(int i=1; i < obj.size(); i++){
                newList.add(new ResultModelClass(
                        String.valueOf(obj.get(i).getId()),
                        obj.get(i).getName(),
                        obj.get(i).getSurname());
            }

            n1RecyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerN1View);
            n1RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            n1ListAdapter adapter = new ResultAdapter(newList);
            n1RecyclerViewLM = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
            n1RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(n1RecyclerViewLM);
            n1RecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            n1RecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d("_API_TEST", "Offline mode");
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("_OFFLINE_MODE", "setCatsInfo has problem: "+e);
        }

    }
```

Everything looks good for me, exactly the same example but after try im getting question if response.code == 200 then download and parse data using this same newList.add mode, and it's work.
Im very confused... Im also trying with making two recyclerviews names like "n1RecyclerView" and "n1RecyclerView2" but it's for nothing.

Comment: Seems that it couldn't get your recyclerN1View from XML file. Is your XML file contains any recyclerview named with recyclerN1View?

Comment: Yeah it's it. :)

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView reference null there. getActivity() it's a generic activity reference. So, you've to cast your activity.

```
((YOUR_ACTIVITY) getActivity()).findViewById(R.id.recyclerN1View);
```

Comment: I know it but this is not a problem with activity recognizing, it's a problem with next functions, findview is working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it.
There is a problem with that, this view will load too fast.
The simplest answer is to use delay like:

```
    import android.os.Handler;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         RealmResults<ResultModel> obj = realm.where(ResultModel.class).findAll();
            for(int i=1; i < obj.size(); i++){
                newList.add(new ResultModelClass(
                        String.valueOf(obj.get(i).getId()),
                        obj.get(i).getName(),
                        obj.get(i).getSurname());
            }
        n1RecyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recyclerN1View);
        n1RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        n1ListAdapter adapter = new ResultAdapter(newList);
        n1RecyclerViewLM = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        n1RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(n1RecyclerViewLM);
        n1RecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        n1RecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d("_API_TEST", "Offline mode");
}
}, 500);
```